# How can triple integral of $x+y+z$ with boundary an offcentered sphere can be reduced to the sum of centerpoints times the volume of the spere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, recreational-mathematics, education

Hello everyone I was looking at a solution of a triple integral and was wondering why this step holds. If someone could take the time to clarify this, your awesome! Thanks in advance.

Question:
$$\iiint_D (x^2+y^2+z^2) \,dV$$
with D:
$$(x-3)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-7)^2 \leq 9$$
Is the same as
$$(\bar{x}+\bar{y}+\bar{z}) V$$
with $\bar{x}=3$, $\bar{y}=2$, $\bar{z}=7$ and V the volume of the sphere.

Comment: why is $\bar{z}=7$? Assuming that is a typo, I can think of many examples where this wouldn't hold, for example, where $\bar{x}+\bar{y}+\bar{z}\leq 0$ would suggest the integral is also nonpositive, but the integrand is strictly nonnegative and must produce a strictly positive answer always.

Comment: @NinadMunshi yes that's indeed a typo, my mistake. I will adjust it. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any sphere of the form $(x-\bar{x})^2+(y-\bar{y})^2+(z-\bar{z})^2 \leq r^2$ we can rewrite the integral and show that

$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = (x-\bar{x})^2+(y-\bar{y})^2+(z-\bar{z})^2+2(\bar{x}x+\bar{y}y+\bar{z}z)-(\bar{x}^2+\bar{y}^2+\bar{z}^2)$$

$$= \Bigr[(x-\bar{x})^2+(y-\bar{y})^2+(z-\bar{z})^2\Bigr]+2\Bigr[\bar{x}(x-\bar{x})+\bar{y}(y-\bar{y})+\bar{z}(z-\bar{z})\Bigr]+\Bigr[\bar{x}^2+\bar{y}^2+\bar{z}^2\Bigr]$$

The three terms in brackets are easy to analyze

$$\iiint\limits_V\Bigr[(x-\bar{x})^2+(y-\bar{y})^2+(z-\bar{z})^2\Bigr]dV = \frac{3}{5}r^2V $$

$$\iiint\limits_V2\Bigr[\bar{x}(x-\bar{x})+\bar{y}(y-\bar{y})+\bar{z}(z-\bar{z})\Bigr]dV = 0$$

$$\iiint\limits_V\Bigr[\bar{x}^2+\bar{y}^2+\bar{z}^2\Bigr]dV=(\bar{x}^2+\bar{y}^2+\bar{z}^2)V$$

by spherical coordinates, odd symmetry, and volume times a constant, respectively. This means the final answer is

$$\iiint\limits_V\Bigr[x^2+y^2+z^2\Bigr]dV = \left(\frac{3}{5}r^2+\bar{x}^2+\bar{y}^2+\bar{z}^2\right)V$$

Edited to match OP's notation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if your calculations are right, doesn't this disprove what I'm trying to figure out? Because now there is an extra term $\frac{3r^2}{5}$

Comment: @TheCreator my counterexample in my comment showed that what you were trying to prove could never be correct. This new term not only has the extra fraction, but also the values of $\bar{x}$, etc are squared which is different from the original proposition. Another way to think about it, the final answer had to be independent of octant by mirror symmetry, so flipping the center of the sphere over by changing the sign of any of the coordinates should not affect the value of the integral. With this sanity check, this answer is sign independent but the first is not.

Answer (score 0):

$I = \displaystyle \iiint_D r^T r dV$

Let $u = r - C$ where $C$ is the center of the sphere, then

$I = \displaystyle \iiint_S (u + C)^T (u + C) d V $

Expanding

$I = \displaystyle \iiint_S \left(u^T u + 2 C^T u + C^T C \right) dV $

From symmetry, the second term contributes zero to the integral, and the integral reduces

$I = \displaystyle \iiint_S \left(u^T u + C^T C \right) d V $

The second term contributes $C^T C V = (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) V $

The first term is just $ \rho^2 $  where $ 0 \le \rho \le r $ hence its integral will yield $ \dfrac{ 4 \pi r^5 }{5} = \dfrac{3 r^2}{5} V $

hence, the integral is

$ I = ( a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + \dfrac{3 r^2}{5} ) V $